# Is it possible to automate writing text into an existing DOS program that has text inputs?

Tags: dos

For example, I have a DOS program that prompts for a file input name. It uses that name to find the file needed to run analysis on and also to generate the output report filename. If I had a list of filenames that I wanted to run in the program, can I automate the action of writing those filenames into the dos program one by one and running the program for each one somehow? Ideally, I could run the program for all filenames by just clicking go somehow.

Comment: I assume it's the Windows Command Line (`cmd`), not `DOS`, an old console based operating system? Looks like a job for the [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) command.

Comment: `program.exe < textinput.txt`